# After Effects CC slant effect crops artwork

Tags: after-effects

I'm a newbie to AE so there's probably a simple answer to this. So I've imported some art from illustrator and dropped in on the stage. I then `Create shapes from vector layer`. Then I apply the effect `CC Slant` under the Distort menu under Effects and give the slant a value of 50.

[image]

Looking good. Until I move it to the edge of the stage and then the artwork gets cropped. Notice how only the "mple" of "Example" are visible:

[image]

Even after rendering the movie (with the position changing from center stage to left stage while slanted), the problem persists. I have tried re-importing my artwork, and applying the slant effect while the artwork is in different positions on the stage to no avail. I've also tried other effects like the warp effect, and the same thing happens.

Is there a way to keep the artwork from getting cropped on the edge of the stage?

Comment: This is very odd and not expected behavior.  I have nothing in the way of answers for you but wanted to comment that it isn't just you.  This is bizarre.

Comment: @AJHenderson thanks, maybe I should post the problem in an Adobe CC forum...

Comment: I don't think so, bc I created shapes from the layer. I can tell you for sure it's not part of a composition.. I even tried scaling it down, applying the effect and then pre-composing it, and scaling up the composition, to no avail.

Comment: I would offer to let you post the project and I'd take a look, but unfortunately, I don't have CC because I refuse to allow my access to my work to be ransomed to me.  I updated my answer below with an idea to try working around it though.

Comment: @AJHenderson yea the subscription pay model is super annoying. Still on a free trial right now, but I feel your pain. I understand why they did it, but it has some major downfalls for the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you imported it, it is possible that it ended up nested as a nested composition or smart object.  If you applied the effect to the outer object but then dragged it within the inner object, you could end up dragging it off the edge of the outer object which would produce the result you are experiencing.

Effectively, you would have an outer object that is tilted and an inner object that is going off the edge of the outer.  Thus, the outer object displays only the half of the object you see and then the skew gets applied (which makes the otherwise vertical clipping to be angled.)

That's the only thing that occurs to me as a possible cause.

Even if that isn't it, a work around might be to put the original graphic in a composition and then apply the effect to the composition instead and then move the composition as you need.  This would probably work around whatever issue you are having here.

Comment: The part of your answer that worked was creating a composition from the art and applying CC Slant to the composition. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just pre-compose the layer with the CC Slant effect, and make this new comp a little wider than Your main comp. The crop will still happen but You won´t see in Your main comp, because it´s out of frame.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Transform effect (**effects>distort>transform** IIRC), and use the skew setting to achieve the same thing. It always works reliably for me.